# How do you color the edges of a graph based on whether they are homophilous in igraph?

Tags: r, igraph

This feels like it should be a fairly visualization technique but I cannot figure out a good way to do it.

Let's say I have the following graph:

```
G = make_undirected_graph(c(1,2,
                            2,3,
                            3,4))

V(G)$attribute = c(T,T,T,F)
```

I want to make a plot where the edge color differs based on whether the two vertices have the same value for `attribute`.

Answer (score 2):

Seemingly easy tasks like this drove me crazy when I tried to learn `igraph`. I find it much easier to work with `tidygraph` now, which uses `tidyverse` verbs to manipulate `igraph` objects. It comes with a companion package for plotting, developed by the same people and following the logic implemented by `ggplot2` (grammer of graphics).

```
library(ggraph)
library(tidygraph)
G %>% 
  as_tbl_graph() %>% 
  activate(edges) %>% # this determines if edges or nodes are manipulated
  mutate(agreement = .N()$attribute[from] == .N()$attribute[to]) %>% # .N() makes the node data available while manipulating edges
  ggraph() + # using ggraph to plot
  geom_node_point() + 
  geom_edge_link(aes(colour = agreement)) +
  theme_graph()
```

[image]

You can also mix and match `igraph` and `tidygraph`/`ggraph` as `tidygraph` objects are still valid `igraph` objects as well:

```
G2 <- G %>% 
  as_tbl_graph() %>% 
  activate(edges) %>% # this determines if edges or nodes are manipulated
  mutate(agreement = .N()$attribute[from] == .N()$attribute[to]) %>% 
  mutate(color = ifelse(agreement, "green", "red"))
plot(G2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I like the `tidygraph`/`ggraph` solution, but if you are interested, here's how to do it in `igraph`.

```r
library(igraph)

G = make_undirected_graph(c(1,2,
                            2,3,
                            3,4))

V(G)$attribute = c(T,T,T,F)

# Get the index for nodes with the attribute
idx <- which(V(G)$attribute)

# Assign the "non-homophilous" color
E(G)$color <- "tomato"

# Assign the "homophilous" color using the index and the `%--%` operator

E(G)[idx %--% idx]$color <- "steelblue"


plot(G)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-03-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

This could be generalized to attributes with an arbitrary number of features:

```r
G <- igraph::sample_gnp(150, 0.05)

V(G)$gender <- sample(c("M", "F", "NB"), 150, replace = TRUE)

m_idx <- which(V(G)$gender == "M")
f_idx <- which(V(G)$gender == "F")
nb_idx <- which(V(G)$gender == "NB")

E(G)$color <- "tomato"
E(G)[m_idx %--% m_idx]$color <- "steelblue"
E(G)[f_idx %--% f_idx]$color <- "steelblue"
E(G)[nb_idx %--% nb_idx]$color <- "steelblue"

plot(G, vertex.size = 5, vertex.label = NA)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-03-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

```r
library(dplyr)
library(igraph)

G <- sample_gnp(150, 0.05)

V(G)$quant <- runif(150)

epsilon <- 0.5

G <- G %>% 
  igraph::as_data_frame() %>% 
  mutate(diff = abs(V(G)$quant[.[,1]] - V(G)$quant[.[,2]]) > epsilon) %>% 
  graph_from_data_frame(directed = FALSE)

E(G)$color <- ifelse(E(G)$diff, "steelblue", "tomato")

plot(G, vertex.size = 5, vertex.label = NA, color = diff)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-03-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks so much! I have another puzzle for you. Is there a way to do this with a continuous attribute? E.g., something like `if abs(vertex1.attribute - vertex2.attribute) < epsilon`, then have a certain color?   It seems like the `tidygraph` solution would probably allow for this, but maybe not in base igraph?

Comment: @Jeremy yeah, sort of tricky to do in straight `igraph`. Tricky to index vertices based on an edge query. You can cheat by exporting an edgelist and reimporting it. I added this.